# Observable zip in rxJava2 for Android

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I used to develop a lot in rxJava1 for Android and I loved the zip Operator. Unfortunately I can't get it running on rxJava2. Please can someone help me out? I'm trying to do the following

```
Observable
    .zip(
        Observable.just(“1”), 
        Observable.just(“2"), 
        Observable.just(“3”), 
        Observable.just(“4"),
        new Func4<String, String, String, String, MyResult>() {
           @Override
           public MyResult call(String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) {
               return new MyResult(string1, string2, string3, string4);
           }
       });
```

Comment: and, it's not worlking, or? You get an error? I have no clue what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

Java implementation:

```
Flowable.zip(
                Flowable.just("1"),
                Flowable.just("2"),
                Flowable.just("3"),
                Flowable.just("4"),
                new Function4<String, String, String, String, MyResult >() {
                    @Override 
                    public MyResult apply(t1: String, t2: String, t3: String, t4: String) {
                        // return MyResult
                    }
                })
```

Kotlin implementation:

```
Flowable.zip(
                Flowable.just("1"),
                Flowable.just("2"),
                Flowable.just("3"),
                Flowable.just("4"),
                object : Function4<String, String, String, String, MyResult > {
                    override fun apply(t1: String, t2: String, t3: String, t4: String): MyResult {
                        // return MyResult
                    }
                })
```

Comment: change what? why?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Observables are replaced with Flowables in RxJava 2 and many of the methods name.
Please check the answer first. All the things are self-explanatory!!

Comment: *All the things are self-explanatory!!* -- no, they are not. Dumping code with explaining what you changed and for what reason is not useful

Comment: btw "Observables are replaced with Flowables in RxJava 2" this is not true

Comment: But Flowables are recommended. I hope you know that!! Or you need an explanation for that as well?

Comment: Do you really know the purpose of using flowables? How does it relate to the question in this thread?

Comment: I know the difference between flowable and observable. The point is that not everybody reads this knows it as well. That is why you should explain your answer

Comment: Actually, the main answer on the question in this thread that class Func4 was renamed in rxjava2 with Function4, and that is all. Of course, the package name of that classes were also changed. The logic of the zip operator is preserved in the 2nd release. I did not really understand why the author has accepted the answer with flowables, especially that it does not relate to specific case described in the question

Comment: @МаксимПетлюк it is indeed that simple. Which is why answers like this one are bad

Comment: relax guys. The answer helped me out and only this counts. For some reason I did not get the autocomplete for Function4 and then I started to search for the answer on the github page of rxJava2 and in the diff (rx1 to rx2). The answer above was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No, Observables are not replaced by Flowables. Otherwise, `Observable<T>` would not exist in Rx2.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Observable.zip(Observable.just("1"),
            Observable.just("2"),
            Observable.just("3"),
            Observable.just("4"),
            new Function4<String, String, String, String, MyResult>() {

                @Override
                public MyResult apply(String s, String s2, String s3, String s4) throws Exception {
                    return new MyResult(s, s2, s3, s4);
                }
            });
```

And make sure, you use Observable from

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
```

Comment: what did you change, why?

Comment: Because Observable in rxJava1 different with rxJava2. And you can't run your code just updating Rx version (without code modification)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I hope it will work.

```
Observable.zip(getResponse1(), getResponse2(),
    object : BiFunction<Res1, Resp2, Pair<Res1, Resp2>> {
      override fun apply(t1: Res1, t2: Res1): Pair<Res1, Res2> {
        return Pair(t1, t2)
      }
    })
```